# Android Studio App crashes on Activity Start with Bluetooth Code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I just added A new code to my app which is supposed to cennct via bluetooth to an arduino to control it... Im fairly new to programming java. Compiling has not shown any errors so far so I booted it up on my device and it crashes as soon as I open the Activity with the bluetooth code in it. Below you will find my Activity and my error logcat:

I hope someone can help :)

BT_Classic.java:

```
    package com.car.bluetooth.bluetoothcar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;



public class BT_Classic extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button pairedButton;
private Button discoveredButton;
private Button btonButton;
private Button btoffButton;
private ProgressDialog progress;
ListView listView;
BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;


private final static UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("fc5ffc49-00e3-4c8b-9cf1-6b72aad1001a");


private ArrayList<String> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<String>();

BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


//BLUETOOTH VERBINDUNG


private static final int REQUEST_ENABLED = 0;
private static final int REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE = 0;

    private class ConnectingThread extends Thread {

        public ConnectingThread(BluetoothDevice device) {


            BluetoothSocket temp = null;
            BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = device;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                temp = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bluetoothSocket = temp;

        }


            public void run() {
        // Cancel any discovery as it will slow down the connection
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            // This will block until it succeeds in connecting to the device
            // through the bluetoothSocket or throws an exception
            bluetoothSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            connectException.printStackTrace();
            try {
                bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
                closeException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Code to manage the connection in a separate thread
    /*
        manageBluetoothConnection(bluetoothSocket);
    */
    }

    // Cancel an open connection and terminate the thread
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            bluetoothSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}








@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bt__classic);


    pairedButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pairedButton);
    discoveredButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.discoveredButton);
    btonButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btonButton);
    btoffButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btoffButton);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String  itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String MAC = itemValue.substring(itemValue.length() - 17);
            BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MAC);
            // Initiate a connection request in a separate thread
            ConnectingThread t = new ConnectingThread(bluetoothDevice);
            t.start();
        }
    });

    //Pairing Button

    pairedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();

            ArrayList<String> devices = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices){
                devices.add(bt.getName());
                devices.add(bt.getAddress());

            }

            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(BT_Classic.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, devices);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    });








    discoveredButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(!btAdapter.isDiscovering()){
                Intent bton = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                startActivityForResult(bton, REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            }


        }
    });

    btonButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent bton = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(bton, REQUEST_ENABLED);
        }
    });

    btoffButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btAdapter.disable();
        }
    });










}
}
```

Error Logcat:

```
2018-09-18 17:48:10.947 31085-31085/com.car.bluetooth.bluetoothcar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.car.bluetooth.bluetoothcar, PID: 31085
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.car.bluetooth.bluetoothcar/com.car.bluetooth.bluetoothcar.BT_Classic}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2830)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.car.bluetooth.bluetoothcar.BT_Classic.onCreate(BT_Classic.java:121)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1235)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2783)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never initialized your `listView` variable.

Make sure it's initialized under `onCreate()`:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.whateveryourlistviewis);
```